# You're never gonna take me there is it idiom or not

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, phrase-meaning

I was listening an English song. And I confused about that part of the song.

```
You make me so upset sometimes
I feel like I could lose my mind
The conversation goes nowhere
'Cause you're never gonna take me there
```

At the end of this part of song she says "`'Cause you're never gonna take me there`". What I understand is like "`You are not gonna allow me to tend this conversation toward where I want.`"
And I looked the translation of this verse in my native language. One of the translators translated like "`You are not allowing me to speak`" other translator is translated "`You are not gonna understand me`".

When I search at Cambridge Dictionary it says taking someone to somewhere physically, but I don't think she meant that. Am I wrong at my assumption. Is that a idiom or something like that.

Comment: I don't know exactly what "there" means in the cited context, but I certainly wouldn't say it's an "idiom". It's ***song lyrics / poetry***, so it may not have a particularly "fixed" meaning anyway.

Comment: If you read the lyrics to the whole song (https://www.azlyrics.com/lyrics/selenagomezthescene/mydilemma.html), you'll see that the songwriter is vague and misuses words frequently. Ugh. All I can get is that she is upset because the guy is not being honest with her (talking in circles, hiding things, so on), and so "there" probably means that he just won't be honest with her. It's a clumsy and confusing construction.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's about the meaning of song lyrics (i.e. - a matter of opinion).

Comment: @FumbleFingers okey then.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first comment about song lyrics/poetry seems fairly accurate, but knowing a little bit more about the songwriter's origin and background would help clarify the extent to which it's idiomatic -- the second comment sheds some light on that re: saccharine/meaningless record industry songwriting.

It's probably a matter of opinion whether this qualifies as a full-blown 'idiom' or just vernacular / laziness, but there *could* be double entendre at work between usage of 'take me there' in the sense of 'bring to a destination' as a synonym for 'explain', 'persuade', or 'convince', and 'take me there' as in 'reach sexual completion'. The lyrical structure, and I suppose, shades of poetic nuance seem to make sense in light of that vernacular usage, and certainly the phrase and connotations of 'take me there' here aren't original to the songwriter behind this gold... and it is probably idiomatic to the extent that it could lead to confusion for a non-native speaker, whereas a native speaker from a different region / generation or just not immediately on the same wavelength of phrasing could understand the implicit meanings fairly quickly. It's got a certain bland banality or ubiquity to it that might make it cliché without having the longevity or universality of full-blown idiomatic phrasing.

An image that comes to mind to illustrate the 'nowness' that I associate with the phrase looks something like this, purely given as speculative illustration that might be helpful: a TED talk where the speaker presents an idea that, at first glance, appears absurd or counterintuitive, but, "over the next 18 minutes, I hope to take you on a journey to a place where dissecting lyrics written for Selena Gomez will become a rewarding part of your daily ritual."